# Attempt to suggest CLJS as synonym for ClojureScript fails

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I [was on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clojurescript/synonyms) for the tag "ClojureScript", and attempted to add "CLJS" as a synomym.

[image]

However, when I click the "Suggest" button, I get an error:

[image]

So, it almost sounds like you can't add a tag to the system unless the tag is already in the system!???

Is there a solution to this dilemma?